# CSS background not working?

Tags: html, css

I cannot understand why the css background property is not working. I have looked at multiple SO answers and cannot find a solution. Here is a simple example that doesn't work for me. I have tried multiple image urls and nothing seems to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mf9LF/

html

```
<body>
<div id="asdf" >

</div>
</body>
```

css

```
#asdf{
   background: url('http://cs618428.vk.me/v618428017/7882/L7GGRmZFKK8.jpg') no-repeat center    center;
   background-size: cover;
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: Would work if the div had content or a height.

Comment: add content to the div or give it a static width and height

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/Mf9LF/1/

```
#asdf{
  background: url('http://cs618428.vk.me/v618428017/7882/L7GGRmZFKK8.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; 
}
```

Div needs height or content within to force a height.